How do I implement sort by using algolia in Nextjs
I am facing issue while adding sort by feature in my Nextjs project using algolia
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const index = algoliaClient.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX);
    const filters = choseFilters(cta_type);
    
    if (category_Item_name) {
      index
        .search("", {
          facetFilters: filters,
          page: page,
          hitsPerPage: 20,
          facets:['*']
        })
        .then(({ hits,facets }) => {
          if (page === 0) {
            setSearchResults(hits);
            const filteredFacets = Object.fromEntries(
              Object.entries(facets).filter(([key, _]) => !['Category_en','Object_Type','Sub_Category_en','price','disabled','Sub_Category',selected_language === "ar"?'Brand_name_en':'Brand_name'].includes(key))
            );
            
            setFacets((prevFacets) => {
              const updatedFacets = { ...prevFacets };
              Object.keys(filteredFacets).forEach(key => {
                updatedFacets[key] = {  ...prevFacets[key],...filteredFacets[key] };
              });
              
              return updatedFacets;
            });
          } else {
            setSearchResults((prevResults) => [...prevResults, ...hits]);
          }
          setLoading(false);
          setAlgoliaLength(hits?.length);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Search error:", err);
        });
    }
  }, [category_Item_name, choseFilters, cta_type, page,selected_language]);

Code above is called in GlobalContext.
And I have created a custom drop down as shown in the image currently I am looking for price only
How can I achieve it?
Here is my dropdown code for sort:
const FilterDropdown = () => {
    const items = [
        {
          key: "Relevance",
          label: "Relevance",
        },
        {
          key: "High to Low",
          label: "Price : High to Low",
        },
        {
          key: "Low to High",
          label: "Price : Low to High",
        },
        {
          key: "Popularity",
          label: "Popularity",
        },
        {
          key: "Featured",
          label: "Featured",
        },
        
      ];
  return (
    <Dropdown >
      <DropdownTrigger>
        <Button 
          variant="bordered"
          className='pRegular text-primaryGrey z-9' 
        >
          Relevance <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
        </Button>
      </DropdownTrigger>
      <DropdownMenu aria-label="Dynamic Actions" items={items}>
        {(item) => (
          <DropdownItem
            key={item.key}
            // color={item.key === "delete" ? "danger" : "default"}
            // className={item.key === "delete" ? "text-danger" : ""}
          >
            {item.label}
          </DropdownItem>
        )}
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  )
}

export default FilterDropdown:

I tried adding sortBy parameter - this was not working:
index
        .search("", {
          facetFilters: filters,
          page: page,
          hitsPerPage: 20,
          facets:['*'],
sortBy:['price:asc']
        })


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

For each sorting, you'll need to create a replica index and then add a sort-by attribute.
Full details can be found in the documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/sorting/how-to/sort-by-attribute/
